# Covering One group box with another and using visible property to display one

Tags: vb.net, winforms

WinForms. VB.NET VS 2010 Professional. So I am building a form that has 3 radio buttons on one side of it... Then on the left side I have 2 group boxes named Group1 and Group2 for this question that I have placed in the designer so that the one covers the other one and have set both of the groupboxes visible property to false.. When a user click on the second radio box group1.visible changes to true and group2.Visible changes to false.. When a user clicks on the third radio group1.visible changes to false and group2.visible changes to true. If the user clicks the first radio button both group1 and group2 visible changes to false... Now the problem... This is not working at all.. Only one of the group boxes shows... If I open the designer and ONLY change which one is on the bottom then it will show and not the other.. The subs that handle the logic are below:

```
Private Sub SP_Radio_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SP_Radio.GotFocus
    SP_Radio.Checked = True
    OP_Radio.Checked = False
    AP_Radio.Checked = False
    If SP_Radio.Checked = True Then
        unitType = 0
        ApartmentGroup.Visible = False
        OfficeGroup.Visible = False
        Call _setLabelColors(False)
    End If
    p_saveChangesButton.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub OP_Radio_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OP_Radio.GotFocus
    OP_Radio.Checked = True
    AP_Radio.Checked = False
    SP_Radio.Checked = False
    If OP_Radio.Checked = True Then
        unitType = 1
        ApartmentGroup.Visible = False
        OfficeGroup.Visible = True
        Call _setLabelColors(True)

    End If
    p_saveChangesButton.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub AP_Radio_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AP_Radio.GotFocus
    AP_Radio.Checked = True
    OP_Radio.Checked = False
    SP_Radio.Checked = False
    If AP_Radio.Checked = True Then
        unitType = 2
        OfficeGroup.Visible = False
        ApartmentGroup.Visible = True
        Call _setLabelColors(True)
    End If
    p_saveChangesButton.Focus()
End Sub
```

Any ideas????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **You can not put one groupbox on another group box. If do this overlapping group box will become the child of the below group box.
>   you can implement this using the Panel control.**

Put your radio button in group box and then place your both group box separate( should not overlap each other). Now use the following code and it works.

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                groupBox1.Visible = false;
                groupBox2.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                groupBox1.Visible = true;
                groupBox2.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                groupBox1.Visible = false;
                groupBox2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Now Little Change, Put two Panel Controls overlapping each other and check this:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                panel1.Visible = false;
                panel2.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                panel1.Visible = true;
                panel2.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                panel1.Visible = false;
                panel2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Now it will work as you want

Comment: Ok this worked.. But I had to offset the x coordinate by 1 for the top panel. It wasn't working but your mention of the one becoming the child of the other led me to try offsetting the x coordinate and it works now as it should... Thanks much for the help..

Answer (score 1):

You set the checked property inside a checkedChanged event triggering the CheckedChanged event on the corresponding radiobutton. This will change the current visible left GroupBox based on the last triggered CheckedChanged event.

A simple way out is to disable all the event handlers before changing the checked property and reenable them when you have finished

```
Try
    RemoveHandler AP_Radio.CheckedChanged, AddressOf AP_Radio_CheckedChanged
    RemoveHandler OP_Radio.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OP_Radio_CheckedChanged
    RemoveHandler SP_Radio.CheckedChanged, AddressOf SP_Radio_CheckedChanged

    ' do your work

Finally
    AddHandler AP_Radio.CheckedChanged, AddressOf AP_Radio_CheckedChanged
    AddHandler OP_Radio.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OP_Radio_CheckedChanged
    AddHandler SP_Radio.CheckedChanged, AddressOf SP_Radio_CheckedChanged
End Try
```

To be on the safe encapsulate everything in a Try/Finally block.
In this way the event handlers will be reenabled in case of exceptions.

Comment: No dice... It still acts the same way... As it is right now... When I select radio1 no group is shown... When I select radio2 OfficeGroup is shown.. All correct.. But when I select radio3 no ApartmentGroup is shown and OfficeGroup does as it should and changes to visible false, but ApartmentGroup should be shown and is a valid group. These 2 groups are stacked on top of each other in the designer. With the idea being that the entire form layout stays static and only the group changes based on the radio..

Comment: Have you added the Remove/Add handler to the three events? Are your groupboxes inside panels? Also, could be crazy but, check if the apartment group is contained in the OfficeGroup

Comment: I did do the above as you recommended with my work being done inside the try.. The Group boxes are not inside panels..

Comment: Try to put your two groups apart from one other in design with only one in the correct position. Then when the forms load move the other group in the same location of the first one

Comment: No The problem isn't solved yet... I am trying what you suggested now.. I was at a board meeting all morning...

Comment: Still no dice... I moved one of the Apartment Group down to 38,450 in the designer and left the office group where it was at 26, 138 then used the location = new point(26,138) and location = new point(38,450) for the move before changing visible state. The same results. One shows and the other never shows..

Comment: Its fixed now... I used a bit of you help with the above guys answer and it worked as it should... Thanks much for the help..